# Strange values coming from application config

Tags: c#, app-config

I have c# .net framework 4 client profile application that use app.config with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="someKey" value="newValue"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

When i install application i have file application.exe.config with the same content.

And here is the problem.
When i start application.exe as regular user and load value from config live this

```
var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
string value = configFile.AppSettings.Settings["someKey"].Value;
```

or like this

```
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someKey"];
```

get only "**oldValue**". But when i start application as administrator i get right "**newValue**".

Thanks for replies.

Comment: No way.  There's got to be more going on.

Comment: are you sure you arent picking up a user copy of the file?

Comment: in application folder i have file named application.exe.config.
When i made some changes in it, i can load new values only when i run application.exe as administrator.

Comment: >> What is oldValue?
For example, let it be 123.
When i run application.exe i have 123.

i delete my application and reinstall it.
after this i change file application.exe.config and put there value "qwerty".

When run application.exe as regular user - i get 123. but when i run applicaiton.exe as administrator i get qwerty

Comment: I mean where does `oldValue` come from? There is only one value in your config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are the victim of VirtualStore.

You changed the config file under *Program Files* folder as a user, and the filesystem wrote the change into the users *VirtualStore*, a hidden place inside the users profile.

You then started application as administrator, which doesn't have the file in *its* VirtualStore, hence uses the original file stored inside *Program Files*.

One way to *fix* this is to make the config-file inside *Program Files* read/write for ordinary users - or just edit the config-file as an administrator who has write-access. (and make sure you delete the VirtualStore-version for the user again).

Comment: It was a problem. Thank you very much.